# Minimal projector for Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, hardware, hdmi, display

Currently I have a 3.5" display for my Raspberry Pi 2. This display is lot of fun, but in some cases, it's too small.

I have an idea to use a projector, so I can use it to project the display to a wall or something similar.

Is there such a thing?

I want it to be minimal–not depending on 220V electrical current. Perfectly, it would be a USB + HDMI device that when I connect it to my pi will start projecting the video part.

Where can I get something like this from?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @Ghanima Hmm.. I double-checked the help pages and I guessed it's a good one because it's about hardware. Anyways, I'm happy because I found the answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[helixtech.org.uk](http://www.helixtech.org.uk/raspberry-pi-picopix) reports success using a [Philips PicoPix](http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/PPX2480_EU/picopix-pocket-projector) projector and a couple of minor configuration tweaks. The PicoPix is both USB powered and HDMI fed.

> Add these lines to config.txt to force it to create the correct mode,
>   and use it by default:
>
> ```
> hdmi_cvt=854 480 59.66 3 
> hdmi_group=2 
> hdmi_mode=87
> hdmi_force_hotplug=1 
> hdmi_drive=1
> ```
>
> Set the PicoPix to "Optimal" screen mode in the settings.